# one button to be able to stop all ten buttons

Tags: java, swing

am new in using java, i want to create ten buttons with different functions but i want one button that will be able to stop any of the ten buttons

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dc.android.doctor.v3;

/**
 *
 * @author JAY
 */
public class DCJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DCJFrame
     */
    public DCJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        start = new javax.swing.JButton();
        stop = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");

        jButton4.setText("jButton4");

        jButton5.setText("jButton5");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setText("jButton6");

        jButton7.setText("jButton7");

        jButton8.setText("jButton8");

        jButton9.setText("jButton9");

        jButton10.setText("jButton10");

        start.setText("START");
        start.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                startActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        stop.setText("STOP");
        stop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                stopActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton7)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton8)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton9)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton10)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(start)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(stop)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton9)
                    .addComponent(jButton10))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 146, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(start)
                    .addComponent(stop))
                .addGap(17, 17, 17))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void stopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DCJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DCJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DCJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DCJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DCJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JButton start;
    private javax.swing.JButton stop;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: There's quite a lot of code there - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and in particular the guidance on minimal reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you could make your code better understandable, if you saved all the buttons in a ```List<javax.swing.JButton>```. You could then iterate over them when the main button is pressed

Comment: Also, you have a load of variables named `jButtonN`, where N goes 1, 2, 3, ... . That's a sign you have a collection of things, so instead of having the separate variables, use some kind of collection to hold them (e.g. an array or something in the Collections framework like `java.util.ArrayList`). That will make it easier to manipulate all the items.

Comment: You can have an instance field `boolean running`, which should be marked `true` when `start` button is clicked (actionPerformed of start button), and it should be set to `false` when `stop` button is clicked. All the jButton1 to jButton10's `actionPerformed` implementation should have a number of logical exit points where that instance field's value should be checked and those methods should come out of loops, processes, etc. as soon as possible, when that flag is found to be `false`. There should be graceful exits with proper clean-up of whatever resources those methods are consuming.

Comment: Also, if you want all 10 buttons' actionPerformed to run concurrently, make sure that `jButtonNActionPerformed` method of each button uses SwingWorker (finally a separate thread) to do the button-related process. Otherwise, it will block the event processing thread and actions won't be performed in parallel, but one by one.